# Technologies to implement repository similar to dropbox

Tags: cloud, dropbox, simplerepository

I have do investigate some ways and technologies to implement a server or client-server similar to dropbox (a simple repository)...

Probably I'm not making the best search but I can't find the best technologies to implement or some examples or open source projects that implement the file transfer part...

If you implement something like dropbox what technologies would you use?

Other question is, where is the best place to store all files?

Tks for your help and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding transport - the best bet is either WebDAV/S or SFTP as one of options (SSH supports username/password and custom login schemes). There's no need to invent anything custom.

Files should be stored on the disk (there were plenty of discussions here on SO regarding where and how to store files on such servers) or, if you plan to use cloud services (eg. Azure or Google App Engine) as a backend, in BLOB storage.

In general your question is overly broad - more precise and narrow questions would bring more specific and detailed answers.

Comment: Thanks,

I'll read about WebDAV and find out if that's what I want..

So, I have transport protocol and local disk to store.. There's one thing missing: the programming language.

I've been thinking about use python or ruby (on rails). My objective is implement a server and a website.

What languages do you recomend?

Comment: @user980919 the choice is extremely wide and there's no single recipe to use. Selecting the language to large extent depends on what backend technologies will be used, i.e. will you use platform-as-a-service offers from Google or Microsoft or you would build your own server infrastructure.

Comment: I will build my own server infrastructure. This will be an website (with possibility of expansion to other clients) where scientists can upload their data, share and some other stuffs (like dropbox)... I want to find out my best options for programming language and data management...

Comment: @user980919 basically, whatever language you feel comfortable with. "Which ... is better" discussions are not welcome on StackOverflow. Please re-check the faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple way to have remote "places" where files can be placed and shared, and that can also be mounted as a network share, check the [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) protocol.